# tableview delegate method never called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a viewcontroller, and implement the delegate UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource, so I have following method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{ 
    return [_nameArray count];
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 50;
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return @"name";
}
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
   static NSString *TableIdentifier = @"TableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:TableIdentifier]autorelease];
    }
    UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    nameLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;    
    nameLabel.text = @"100";
    nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:nameLabel];
    [nameLabel release];
    return cell;
}
```

I set a breakpoint for each method, I can find

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

and

`- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

never called,but the other two methods can be called. so what's the problem? thank you.

update:

I have connect datasoucre and delegate to file's owner in IB,but can't solve the problem.

Comment: Are you using IB to build this? Have you linked up the dataSource and delegate properties in IB, or if not using this, in code?

Comment: Make sure that your array count is greater then zero in numberOfRowsInSection method

Comment: yes,you are right.if you answer my question,I will accept...thank you all the same.

Comment: first you can check how many elements in _nameArray. if it is zero then this two method will not call and if it is > 0 then sure you have made mistake to set delegate and dataset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

_nameArray have the 0 objects that's why it's not coming cellForRowAtIndexPath, because if _nameArray is nil or 0 objects delegate method numberOfRowsInSection  returns 0 and it's not coming in both of the above mentioned methods.

For quick check you can return harcoded value say 10 from method numberOfRowsInSection and then see, it will call the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 12):

Most likely its because of delegate reference problem .. make sure you have given proper reference to delegate methods..

In code use these two lines

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have connected the table view to its delegate, either in code or via Interface Builder outlet.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced similar problem. datasource was working but delegate wasn't. If you have added "UITapGestureRecognizer" to "self.view", that is creating problem here. in this case table delegate related to user interaction will not be called. because delegates such as "didSelect" call when any user interaction happen. in this case if there is UITapGestureRecognizer on view , table delegate will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the delegate of the tableView to your class?

Also, unless you're subclassing UITableViewController you should also implement

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have set all the delegates and all then the problem might be the size of UITableview less than the size of cell.